# Is there a program that will display a SQL schema diagram from an existing database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

We have a giant big ass database and we can't visualize it. Is there a program that will scan the database and give us a diagram that we can look at to help us do our jobs better.

Comment: Brace yourself for some frustration time.... Big Ass DBs dot not unfold their secrets just like that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't tried it but you can take a look at ...
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio-help/reverse-engineer-an-existing-database-into-a-database-model-HA010115485.aspx

You will need Visio though for it.

Answer (score 2):

[Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/) can do that.

Answer (score 2):

I once used http://schemaspy.sourceforge.net/ to do that for a MSSQL database. It is pretty good, generates html pages so you can browse. Try it out!

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at [Db Visualizer](http://www.dbvis.com/): the free version will give render Entity Relationship Diagrams for you, and works with any database that has a JDBC driver.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server Management Studio there is a 'Database Diagrams' node. Right click on it and choose 'New Database Diagram'. Select tables you want in your diagram and SSMS will generate it for you.

Comment: I don't have access to those, my DBA doesn't like me.

Comment: Give your DBA something to do than... ask him/her to generate the diagram and send it to you as a bitmap... BTW, if you don't have access to DB Schema none of the tools others mentioned here will work for you.

Comment: I can do that, but it takes like a hour or so before it gets done and I would rather be able to do it myself on any database whenever I want. I should say, we have read write access to our database, just not the ability to do the DB schema tool. I was able to use the Visio reverse engineer tool.

Answer (score 0):

I used Toad Data Modeler for a while.

**Note:** Windows only.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [SQL Dependency Tracker](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-dependency-tracker/), which is developed by the company I work for. However, if you intend to visualize the entire database on one small screen, it might be tough. Consider breaking down your database into logical segments and visualize these individually.